# By Illustrator SDK, how to know if a selected art object is blend type?

Tags: adobe, adobe-illustrator

In Adobe Illustrator, just draw a rectangle and a circle, then give them different colors. Choose AI menu "Object | Blend | Make", before this step you could open "Blend Options..." to set "Specified steps" to an integer. Now you get a series of arts. Using Direct Select Tool you can select the rectangle or circle you drawed at first.

My question is, how to write code to know if the art object you selected is one part of the blended series? Is there any useful suite in SDK? I have looked into the document but cannot find a proper API to get the infomation in AIArtSuite. (for CS5 & CS6)

Cound anyone help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A Blend Object should be registered as a PlugInObject, at least in the [JSX documentation](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/illustrator/scripting/cs6/Illustrator-Scripting-Reference-JavaScript.pdf)(pdf link).

You can try something hacky like this in JSX(javascript):

```
#target illustrator

var doc = app.activeDocument;
var sel = doc.selection;

if(sel.length) alert("is part of blend: " + sel[0].parent.parent.typename == "PluginItem");
```

with an object that is part of a blend selected.

The assumption is the selected object has at least 2 parents: the Group and Blend PlugInItem, but it's not exact. I'm hoping other more exact answers will pop up.